# Is there a task supporting modern multithreaded archivers - 7zip, winrar etc.?

Tags: deployment, ant, zip, 7zip

We are using the [Ant Zip task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html), which is a bit obsolete (low processing speed for big files).

Can anyone point me to a mature Ant task, ready for production use, that supports multithreaded compression/decompression?

First of all I wish to increase speed of processing archive files.

I found [7ZIP Ant task](http://www.pharmasoft.be/7z/), but it looks abandoned, and it doesn't support multithreaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the [exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) with the command line version of 7zip?

Comment: Two points here:
- I wish to decrease dependence from external software (i.e. need to have installed archivator)
- It will be nice to have cross-platform solution

Answer (score 1):

Zip/Jar tasks work well because Java (hence ant) have support for them built in (not sure about the tar support). Built in-support would require 7zip written in Java or at least included in some ant task. It is very easy to write Ant taks. Write you own and shell out to a 7zip/pbzip/etc. If you're REALLY enterprising, give this a shot ... [a LZMA library from 7zip w/ Java support](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/lzma465.tar.bz2)

[7-zip downloads, CLI versions too](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)

To decrease external dependencies, just bundle a version of the cli compression tool you want to use.

I believe many of the executables (7zip specifically) have cli versions for multiple platform.